# How to create Custom UI for Stripe CardForm in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-stripe, custom-ui

```
CardFormField(
              controller: controller,
              onCardChanged: (card) {
                print('card details ${card!.number}');
              },
              dangerouslyGetFullCardDetails: true,
              dangerouslyUpdateFullCardDetails: true,
              style: CardFormStyle(),
            ),
```

```
  Future<void> makePayment() async {

// Create a PaymentMethodData object from the CardParams object.

    try {

      final paymentMethod = await Stripe.instance.createPaymentMethod(
        params: PaymentMethodParams.card(
          paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodData(),
        ),
      );

      print('Payment Method: ${paymentMethod.card.expYear}');
      print('Payment Method: ${paymentMethod.id}');

      // Now you can send the payment method ID to your server for further processing
      // Server-side code should handle the payment and confirm the payment intent
      // See the server-side Stripe documentation for more details
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle errors
      print('Error creating PaymentMethod: $error');
    }
  }
}
```

Stripe provide in Flutter a default CardForm.
I want to create a custom Form to get the user data and provide it to this method. Stripe.instance.createPaymentMethod